# Cant delete pointer, has triggered a breakpoint

Tags: c++, pointers, breakpoints

I learned C++ in on online course, but have a problem with a "delete" statement, in Visual Studio.  When delete is executed, it opens a file `delete_scalar.cpp` and shows:

> ConsoleApplication.exe has triggered a breakpoint. exception thrown

I already move the SymbolCache folder from temp, including wntdll.pdb etc.

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int *pInt = new int;
*pInt = 3;
cout << *pInt << endl;
cout << pInt << endl;

delete[] pInt; //error -- UPDATED: still get error with `delete pInt;` 

return 0;
}
```

here the output info,

> 'ConsoleApplication11.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll'. Symbols loaded.
>   'ConsoleApplication11.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
>   'ConsoleApplication11.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll'. Symbols loaded.
>   'ConsoleApplication11.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcp140d.dll'. Symbols loaded.
>   'ConsoleApplication11.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\vcruntime140d.dll'. Symbols loaded.
>   'ConsoleApplication11.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ucrtbased.dll'. Symbols loaded.
>   The thread 0x2fd0 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
>   HEAP[ConsoleApplication11.exe]: Invalid address specified to RtlValidateHeap( 00930000, 009359E8 )
>   ConsoleApplication11.exe has triggered a breakpoint.

delete_scalar.cpp from the visual itself,

```
//
// delete_scalar.cpp
//
//      Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
//
// Defines the scalar operator delete.
//
#include <crtdbg.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <vcruntime_new.h>
#include <vcstartup_internal.h>

_CRT_SECURITYCRITICAL_ATTRIBUTE
void __CRTDECL operator delete(void* const block) noexcept
{
    #ifdef _DEBUG
    _free_dbg(block, _UNKNOWN_BLOCK); // the circle X symbol showed up there
    #else
    free(block);
    #endif
}
```

I already do the breakpoint things like enable and deleting, but the breakpoint still triggered on the delete_scalar.cpp with circle X symbol showing up.

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: @Muhammad Thanks for editing and adding detail to your question...but please don't edit questions [in a way that makes an answer someone has already given not make sense](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53057590/revisions).  Try to make sure your edits keep the answers valid, and if you can't do that you might need to ask a new question.

Comment: After the update there is no error, it's triggering a breakpoint in the debugger because you placed a breakpoint there to be triggered. Working without problems as seen here https://ideone.com/uaLlN2

Comment: @HostileFork thanks for the advice, and the nice edit.

Comment: @Havenard thanks for the checking problem on other platform, but i didn't place a breakpoint, and if there's placed, how to unplace? now i googleing 'remove breakpoint visual studio', btw thanks again for the breakpoint things.

Comment: @Muhammad Are you sure the program recompiled after changing the `delete[]` to a `delete`?  You might start a fresh project that you are sure you rebuilt fully without the `delete[]`, because that would have definitely caused the problem you saw initially.

Comment: @HostileFork woah its working, start with the new project, copy, then run well. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you ask for memory with `new`, you need to delete it with `delete`.

Only use `delete [ ]` when you used `new [ ]`. Mismatching the two leads to undefined behavior.

Comment: I don't see what else could be wrong, this should work fine.

Comment: @Muhammad are you sure you recompiled it? The shown code using `delete pInt` instead of `delete[] pInt` shouldn't throw any error.

Comment: already edit it without [ ], same error. the delete_scalar.cpp not working properly.

Comment: Works after create a new project, old project have visual studio issues.

Answer (score -1):

I also have similar issue. You can do the following to remove the issue:

Replace:

int *pInt = new int;
*pInt = 3;

By:

int *pInt = new int(3);